# browser stuck when using HTTP request or jQuery post

Tags: jquery, post, browser-cache

I am using HTTP requests in my website, which is most needed through out. But, during the request time (0 sec-70 sec), the browser gets stuck and no typing or selection is not possible.

Any idea how to solve it? This is the code that I am using

```
$.ajax ({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'url',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    data:DataRs,
    success: function (resData) {
    }    
});
```

And also, my cache is not cleared.

Comment: What takes over 70 seconds to load and why?

Comment: change `async: true` and add a valid URL to the `url` property

Comment: Your request is synchronous, that's why your browser sticks. Use ajax as it should be used asynchronously.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the jQuery website.

> async (Boolean) Default: true
>
> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. **Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active.** As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the complete/success/error
>   callbacks.

if you are setting the `async: false` purposely, then its a default behavior. Or you can make it true or remove the property.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thkns all..I changed async:false..Now ,its working without disturbing my browser...:-)

Comment: But,my cache problem still exisits...I have already given something in headers
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache' />
<meta http-equiv='ETag' content='o2389r-98ur0-w3894tu-q894' />
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache' />

and its HTML5

Comment: you can refer to this [document](http://www.i18nguy.com/markup/metatags.html). U can use `cache-control`, `EXPIRES` and `PRAGMA`.